# Ругается на непонятную ошибку синтаксиса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Версия Python -- 3.8.1

Ругается на ошибку синтаксиса в строке, а именно на саму переменную filedata

[image: error]

`filedata = filedata.replace('position', 'Country Manager '+str(country_upper))`

Не могу понять в чём проблема, заранее спасибо!

```py
if department == "lb":
    cname = request.form.get('cname')
    country = request.form.get('country')
    country_upper = country.upper()
    if len(cname) == 0 or len(country) == 0:
        return render_template("error.html")
    filedata = filedata.replace(str("name", str(cname))
    filedata = filedata.replace('position', 'Country Manager '+str(country_upper))
    filedata = filedata.replace('jooble.org', str(country)+'.jooble.org')
    filedata = filedata.replace("+38(044) 333-36-78", "+44(208)638-84-71")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка (не хватает скобки) в предыдущей строчке:

```
filedata = filedata.replace(str("name"), str(cname))
                                      ^
```